# How can I listen for when 'navigationRef' in react navigation becomes ready?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm creating a `react native` app w/ expo, and at the root of my app the following code is returned.

```
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
    <Router />
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
</NavigationContainer>
```

`<Router />` is a custom component. It contains `Stack.Navigator` and my Screens. Also inside of it, it uses `navigationRef` to navigate to an appropriate Screen depending if the user is logged in. How can I listen for when `navigationRef.isReady()` returns true so I can navigate to a different Screen in the `<Router />` component? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following code resolves the above issue for me.

AppNavigation.js

```
export default function AppNavigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
                    fallback={<FullScreenLoadingIndicator visible />}
                    onReady={Navigation.goToInitialRoute}
                    ref={navigationRef}
                    linking={linkingConfig}
                    documentTitle={{
                        enabled: false,
                    }}
                >
                    <AppNavigator authenticated={this.props.authenticated} />
                </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

NavigationService.js

```
export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();
let initialRoute = null;

function navigate(route) {
    console.log(`trying to navigate to ${route}`);
    if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
        console.log(`navigationRef ready, navigating to ${route}`);
        
        // Some business logic, but basically just this
        navigationRef.current.dispatch(someAction);
    } else {
        // Navigation container not yet loaded, set initial route.
        console.log(`navigation not ready, setting initialRoute: ${route}`);
        initialRoute = route;
    }
}

function goToInitialRoute() {
    console.log(`initial route: ${initialRoute}`);
    if (initialRoute) {
        console.log('going to initial route');
        navigate(initialRoute);
    }
}

export default {
    navigate,
    goToInitialRoute,
};
```

Comment: For me it worked only with adding current: `navigationRef?.current?.isReady()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onReady` prop of the `NavigationContainer` as explicitly recommended in the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/).

> Function which is called after the navigation container and all its children finish mounting for the first time. You can use it for:
>
> - Making sure that the ref is usable.

We can use it and set a prop `isReady` and pass this to `Router`.

```js
const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false)

<NavigationContainer onReady={() => setIsReady(true)} ref={navigationRef}>
    <Router ready={isReady} />
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: This didn't work - it's still saying that the object isn't ready. https://bremea.tixte.co/snap_231f0d50.png

Comment: Please,share your Router code including the new prop from my answer.

Comment: Router component code: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/busobilape.js

Comment: You are not using `ready` in the provided implementation.

Comment: I was and it didn't work - it was returning true, then an error was being thrown when I tried to navigate.

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
        if (ready) runMount();
    }, [ready]); ` did not work?

Comment: I have researched a little bit, an [there is an on going discussion](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9170) on Github addressing this issue. That said, my idea might not work as I have expected it to work.

Comment: Try that, `onReady={() => { setIsReady(true) } }`